# Buggy swipe to delete display on one more row after each delete

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios11

I'm having a weird issue on UITableView delete action since iOS 11.

[image]

Here's the relevant TableView code :

```
@implementation ChatMessageListViewController(TableView)

#pragma mark - table view datasource/delegate
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSMutableArray *rowActions = [NSMutableArray array];

    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction * _Nonnull action, NSIndexPath * _Nonnull indexPath) {
        [self deleteMessageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }];
    delete.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [rowActions addObject:delete];
    return [rowActions copy];
}

- (void) deleteMessageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *threadID = [[self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"threadID"];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.messageArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    @weakify(self);
    [UIUtil showLoadingHudWithText:WELocalString(@"message_remove_thread_loading_text", @"Deleting...", @"删除中...")];
    [[AsyncUtil sharedInstance] dispatch_background_network:^{
        DBManager *db = [[DBManager alloc] init];
        [db deletetableData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"singleChat WHERE threadID = '%@' ",threadID] ];
        [[MemChatThreadMessages sharedInstance] removeThread:threadID];
        NSDictionary * result = [Network deleteChatThread:threadID forEmail:[WEUtil getEmail]];
        [[AsyncUtil sharedInstance] dispatch_main:^{
            [UIUtil hideLoadingHuds];
            @strongify(self);
            if(self == nil) return ;

            if([result[@"result"] isEqualToString:@"success"]){
            }else{
                [UIUtil showErrorMessage:WELocalString(@"message_remove_thread_error", @"Cannot delete this thread", @"不能删除该会话！")];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.messageArray count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *messageInfo = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([(NSString *)[messageInfo objectForKey:@"isAnnouncement"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        return 80;
    }else if ([[messageInfo objectForKey:@"chatTag"] isValidString]){
        return 80;
    }else if([self isSpecialMessage:messageInfo]){
        return 80;
    }else{
        return 67;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"message";
    if(self.events == nil){
        NSDictionary * d = [WEUtil getMyEventListCache];
        self.events = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary * eventSummary in d[@"events"]){
            NSString * eventID = eventSummary[@"eventid"];
            [self.events setObject:eventSummary forKey:eventID];
        }
    }
    UserMessageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UserMessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.row >= [self.messageArray count]){
        TERMINATE_WITH_NIL_CELL;
    }

    NSDictionary *messageInfo = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(![self isSpecialMessage:messageInfo]){
        [cell configureCellWithMessageDict:messageInfo];
    }else{
        [cell configureCellWithNewMessageDict:messageInfo withEvents:self.events];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *msgThreadDict = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(![self isSpecialMessage:msgThreadDict]){
        [self tableView:tableView didSelectNormalRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }else{
        NSString * event = msgThreadDict[@"event"];
        if([event isValidString]){
            if([event isEqualToString:@"no_event_messages"]){
                [UIUtil showErrorMessage:@"no event id"];
            }else{
                [BackendTracking trackingWithAction:@"open_special" withLabel:@"threads_list"];
                SpecialTopicListViewController * special = [[SpecialTopicListViewController alloc] init];
                special.tracking_src = @"tab";
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:special animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectNormalRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *msgThreadDict = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *threadID = [msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"threadID"];
    NSString *jid = [msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"jid"];
    [GATracking trackCategory:@"message" withAction:@"thread_list_item_click" withLabel:threadID];
    [[MemChatThreadMessages sharedInstance] setCurrentThreadID:threadID];
    PrivateMessageViewController * chatVC = [[PrivateMessageViewController alloc] init];
    chatVC.threadID = threadID;
    chatVC.targetJID = jid;
    chatVC.targetName = [msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    chatVC.unreadMsgNumber = [[self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"unreadCnt"] integerValue];

    if ([(NSString *)[msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"isGroup"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        chatVC.isGroup = YES;
    }else{
        chatVC.isGroup = NO;
    }
    chatVC.src = @"list";
    WELogInfo(@"click message");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatVC animated:YES];
}
@end
```

With the update and the changes using those trailing swipe actions there is another View appended before each time I delete an entry (until it doesn't work anymore). I've tried disabling the full trail or implementing iOS 11 `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath` but I can't resolve this issue so far.

Do you see something wrong in the code? The main controller code is in another file.

Comment: try reloading after you delete after this line [self.tableView endUpdates]; I think you removed the data from messageArray but as you are not reloading its not reflecting you are reloading inside the block which might be taking time

Comment: tableView reloadData?

Comment: yes. and one more thing you are already removing data from messageArray, and then removeing from db, So if you fail to remove it from db you are showing its not removed but for user it will be removed, as its no longer in message array

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually worked with playing with that around. I'll update my question on Monday. I'll accept your answer then too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading after you delete, after this line 
[self.tableView endUpdates]; 
I think you removed the data from messageArray but as you are not reloading just after that so table view count is still 2 and you are reloading inside the block which might be taking time.

And one more thing you already removing data from messageArray, and then removing from db, So if you fail to remove it from db you are showing its not removed but for user it will be removed, as its no longer in message array

Comment: Playing around with reloadData and the advice concerning the messageArray helped a lot and fixed my issue. Thank you.